# how to increase range of getCurrentPlaces in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

PendingResult result =
            Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
        Log.d("Hello", "Got results: " + likelyPlaces.getCount() + " place found.");

        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
            Log.i("Hello", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                    placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
        }

        likelyPlaces.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Add some more informations to your question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no range in term of distance. This method return upto max of 10 https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place